# How to delete fields for all documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a specific Field for all documents in Firestore, how can I do this?
Since there is no document of this question on Firebase, Stackoverflow, etc. I know it is possible to delete a Field for a single Documents using the SDK, so I have no choice to fetch all the Documents from Firestore and delete the Field for each Collections by SDK's delete()?

For example, if remove 'first_name' from 'users'

**Before**

```json
Collection : users

Document: A
{
  "id": "A",
  "first_name": "Sid",
  "last_name": "Wilson"
}

Document: B
{
  "id": "B",
  "first_name": "Joey",
  "last_name": "Jordison"
}

Document: C
{
  "id": "C",
  "first_name": "Chris",
  "last_name": "Fehn"
}
```

**After**

```json
Collection : users

Document: A
{
  "id": "A",
  "last_name": "Wilson"
}

Document: B
{
  "id": "B",
  "last_name": "Jordison"
}

Document: C
{
  "id": "C",
  "last_name": "Fehn"
}
```

Comment: Is "users" and array in each document or each object in the array is a document of "users" collection?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Sorry, i wrote it in a very confusing way, so i've corrected the example. I was describing it based on the json output from Firestore.

My question is to delete a specific Field from all Documents in the collection(in this example, "users").

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no other way. You can try running the code I've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulks writes are not possible in Firestore at the moment and to update any document you need a reference to it i.e. the document ID. That means you would have to read all the documents, get a reference to them and update them.

```js
// Reading all documents
const colRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users")
const colSnapshot = await colRef.get()

const delField = {first_name: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()}

// Array of update promises
const updates = colSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => colRef.doc(doc.id).update(delField))
// Run the promises simulatneously
await Promise.all(updates)
```

It'll cost N reads and write where N is number of documents but this seems to be the only way. Unless you have array of document IDs somewhere else (it'll prevent reads as you already know the doc IDs).